# Rails 3 geo positioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I am developing a Rails 3 application which I intend to use GEO positioning (long,lat).
Both to save the users current position and to use this to find people in the near proximity.

Do you guys know of a good stabile Rails 3 gem that can do GEO stuff?

Thankful for all tips!

Answer (score 2):

See http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/geocoding___maps.html

geokit + geokit_rails

Comment: Thanks! But are they really Rail 3 compatible?

Comment: Yes... but it has some problems with umlauts (ä,ü,ö,...) I Think thats because of ruby 1.9 new utf-8 support

Comment: Ah ok, but if I use 1.8 of Ruby, will it work fine then? I search everywhere but I cannot find a place where you get step by step instructions on how to setup the Geokit gem. Not the first steps in the process anyway. Do you know where to start?

Comment: It does in a way but I am using Rails 3 and it seems to only fit Rails 2. I have how ever tried this https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3 but I cannot find where to enter GEO provider details.

Comment: Im using it in rails 3 with ruby 1.9.2-head and it works (beside the umlauts).. Just add the gem to the gemfile and install it..

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but exactly where to I enter GEO provider API details? Do I just add the gem to the gem-file and then run bundle install? Is there no other settings to be done?

Comment: Yeah you are right.. You have to put following file into an initializer: https://github.com/andre/geokit-rails/blob/master/assets/api_keys_template

Answer (score 0):

[Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) looks great and supports rails 3.